# PHP Symfony EasyAdmin - configure actions - change newAction to handle collections

Tags: php, symfony4, easyadmin

I have php symfony 4 app and in easy admin i want to change form from User list:
[image]

to User checkbox:

[image]

In my backend code to change above i changed code from:

```
            if ($fieldId == 'user') {
            $options = [
                'class' => 'App\Entity\User',
            ];
```

to code:

```
            if ($fieldId == 'user') {
            $options = [
                 'class' => 'App\Entity\User', 
                 'multiple' => true, 
                 'expanded' => true,
           ];
```

and my backend code:

```
    namespace App\Controller\EasyAdmin;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\EasyAdminController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Event\EasyAdminEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Entity\{Report, CatalogList, CatalogListUser};
use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


class CatalogListUserController extends EasyAdminController
{
    // public function createNewFormBuilder($entity, $view)
    public function createEntityFormBuilder($entity, $view)
    {
        $id = $this->getUser()->getId();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $conn = $em->getConnection();
        $sql = "SELECT id, `name` FROM `catalog_list` WHERE user_id = $id AND status = 1";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $choices = [];
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $choices[$row['name']] = $row['id'];
        }
        
        $ids = [];
        if ($view === 'edit') {
            $selected = $entity->getUser()->getListUsers();
            foreach ($selected as $s){
                $ids[] = $s->getId();
            }
        }

        $formBuilder = parent::createEntityFormBuilder($entity, $view);
        
        // Lists - checkbox
        $formBuilder->add('catalogLists', ChoiceType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'label' => 'Listy',
            'choices' => $choices, 
            'data' => $ids,          
        ]);

        $fields = $formBuilder->all();
        foreach ($fields as $fieldId => $field) {
            
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // - list choice - changed from:
            /* 
            if ($fieldId == 'user') {
                $options = [
                    'class' => 'App\Entity\User',
                ];
            */
            
            // checkbox choice - changed to:
            /* */    
            if ($fieldId == 'user') {
                $options = [
                     'class' => 'App\Entity\User', 
                     'multiple' => true, 
                     'expanded' => true,
                     'choice_label' => 'name',  // to del ?
               ];
               
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                
                $options['query_builder'] = function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('e');
        
                    return $qb->where($qb->expr()->eq('e.company', ':company'))
                        ->setParameter('company', $this->getUser()->getCompany())
                        ->orderBy('e.firstname', 'DESC');
                };
                $formBuilder->add($fieldId, EntityType::class, $options);
            } 
        }
           

        return $formBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * The method that is executed when the user performs a 'new' action on an entity.
     *
     * @return Response|RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function newAction()
    {
        $this->dispatch(EasyAdminEvents::PRE_NEW);

        $entity = $this->executeDynamicMethod('createNew<EntityName>Entity');

        $easyadmin = $this->request->attributes->get('easyadmin');
        $easyadmin['item'] = $entity;
        $this->request->attributes->set('easyadmin', $easyadmin);

        $fields = $this->entity['new']['fields'];
    
    

        $newForm = $this->executeDynamicMethod('create<EntityName>NewForm', [$entity, $fields]);

    
    
        // after change from form list User (one) to form checkbox User(more then one) here is error: Expected argument of type "App\Entity\User or null", "instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given at property path "user".
        
        

        $newForm->handleRequest($this->request);    
        
        
        
        if ($newForm->isSubmitted() && $newForm->isValid()) {

            foreach ($entity->catalogLists as $id) {

                // check if already exists
                $catalogList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(CatalogList::class)->find($id);
                $catalogListUser = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(CatalogListUser::class)->findOneBy(['user' => $entity->getUser(), 'list' => $catalogList, 'status' => 1]);
                // add to database
                if (!$catalogListUser) {
                    $newEntity = clone $entity;
                    $newEntity->setList($catalogList);
                    $this->dispatch(EasyAdminEvents::PRE_PERSIST, ['entity' => $newEntity]);
                    $this->executeDynamicMethod('persist<EntityName>Entity', [$newEntity, $newForm]);
                    $this->dispatch(EasyAdminEvents::POST_PERSIST, ['entity' => $newEntity]); 
                }
            }

            return $this->redirectToReferrer();
        }

        $this->dispatch(EasyAdminEvents::POST_NEW, [
            'entity_fields' => $fields,
            'form' => $newForm,
            'entity' => $entity,
        ]);

        $parameters = [
            'form' => $newForm->createView(),
            'entity_fields' => $fields,
            'entity' => $entity,
        ];

        return $this->executeDynamicMethod('render<EntityName>Template', ['new', $this->entity['templates']['new'], $parameters]);
    }

    protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null, $dqlFilter = null)
    {

        $response =  parent::createListQueryBuilder('CatalogListUser, User', $sortDirection, $sortField, $dqlFilter); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

        $response->join('entity.user','user');
        $response->andWhere('user.company = :company')->andWhere('entity.status = 1')->setParameter('company', $this->getUser()->getCompany());

        return $response;
    }
}
```

and in line:

```
$newForm->handleRequest($this->request);
```

i have error:
Expected argument of type "App\Entity\User or null", "instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given at property path "user".

My question:
How to change this code to transform my new data (checkbox, not one choice) to Collection to save this correctly?

regards